# Sending a http post request is not working

Tags: java, php, android, http-post

I'm making an android app and run it on the simulator. All post parameters on the server are empty when I send a http post request. This is code in the android app:

```
public void run() {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(page);

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        InputStreamReader inreader = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inreader);
        String line = "";
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(line);
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

And this is the code on the server:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

It returns an empty php array when I run it on the simulator.

Comment: It looks like you need an identifier for the $_POST -> example: $_POST['item_that_was_posted_here']

Comment: have you provided Internet permission in manifest file?

Comment: If you have access to the web server logs check if app sends data correctly.

Comment: Robuust, `print_r($_POST)` will display all identifier in an post. Tamir no, actually I get a server response that displays: `array( )` hari, yes.

Comment: @antoniom when I output the `$_SERVER` variable, then I see REQUEST_METHOD returns `GET` so probaly thats the problem?

Comment: check your web logs - do you see the POST request in there? what is the response code? are you being redirected from POST to GET?

Comment: @HorusKol yes... is this a server side problem?

Comment: redirected? most likely a server issue: there could be a rewrite rule on the server, or something in your scripts - i don't see where you are sending the request to in your Java code.

Comment: OK.do one thing. $_POST['test']='yes', then print_r($_POST) ?? may be register_global variable off on your php side.

Comment: what happens if you create a simple HTML web form to POST to your server?  Does that print the form params and show up as a POST request?

Comment: @GBD [register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) should always be off. Superglobals like $_POST will be populated regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put www in the request url and it was solved. There was a htaccess file that corrected all url`s without www.

Answer (score 0):

Volley Library(sim-official from google) is better, http, https etc.
https://developers.google.com/live/shows/474338138

There's a very mini sample here:
https://github.com/ogrebgr/android_volley_examples/blob/master/src/com/github/volley_examples/Act_SimpleRequest.java

There's the same question like you here: [Optimizing HTTP requests in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18226697/optimizing-http-requests-in-android/18226899#18226899)